# Appcelerator - CodeSign issue since adding new UDIDs to provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, appcelerator, codesign

I recently added some new UDIDs to my AdHoc Distribution Provisioning profile. I then downloaded the updated certificate and since then I have been able to publish my iPhone app as I keep getting a 'Codesign' issue.

I've tried everything seen in many other posts on this forum including deleting and recreating my developer and production certificates and deleting and recreating my provisioning certificates (Both Developer and Ad Hoc Distribution).

I now can't even 'run' the app to my iPhone attached to the computer (which wasn't one of the new UDIDs - deployment to this phone has always worked).

I'm at a loss where to turn as

- Apple tells me my Provisioning Profiles are 'Active' [image: Apple Certs] [image: Apple Profiles]
- Xcode shows the correct Provisioning profiles [image: XCode]
- My Key Chain tells me I have two valid certificates (one iPhone developer, one iPhone Distribution). [image: Keychain]
- Appcelerator gives me all the ticks when I am choosing which profiles to use in the build [image: Appcelerator]
- I have been 'cleaning' my app and restarting Appcelerator like crazy but with no luck [image: Error]

I really need to get this app over to the client, but have no idea what is 'wrong' as everything matches up. Is it possible Xcode has cached old certificates? Has something got corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

I have been through this issue in past month, the problem was exactly same as yours, everything was showing correctly.

But from your Keychain screenshot, I think there is no private key (this was my case also) attached with your certificates which is the issue of CodeSign.

If you even install the .cert file, it will still show it as a valid certificate, but you might not be able to sign your code due to missing private key.

So, make sure you get the private key added along with the certificate in your keychain. If it does not works for you then you should create new certificates from same machine you will distribute the app as it will save a lot your headaches :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prashant... Could you just expand how I get my key added please? Sorry for the Noob question!

Comment: See this [CodeSign.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzkw0r0gtq5b5oe/CodeSign.txt?dl=0) file to know further steps. I had to create a text file due to character-limit here.

After reading that file, process of creating Provisioning Profile is same.

Comment: Thank you so much for the instructions. I will give that a go!

Comment: Hi @prashant-saini. Thanks for your detailed response. Whilst it wasn't the fix I needed I hope it i will help others.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case - this was a very simple issue wrapped up as a complex one.

When creating a build (both under 'Run' and 'Package'), you can select which KeyChain to use. Somehow this dropdown had changed from 'System Defaults' to another one... changing this Select KeyChain drop down back to System Defaults was all I had to do!

Thanks to @prashant-saini for getting me thinking about keys and keychains!

Comment: Good to hear that you have solved it, but I could not point out at Keychain areas as one of your attached screenshot shows the System keychain selected.